# Sitecore Cross linking of assets in multiple sites

Tags: cross-domain, sitecore, media, sitecore7, sitecore-media-library

I have following tree structure in Sitecore 7

```
Content
    Site 1
        page 1
    Site 2
        page 1
Media Library
    Site 1 media files
        pdf
            1.pdf
    Site 2 media files
        pdf
            1.pdf
```

Media library is a shared library and looks like user can access site 2 media files from site 1 and site 1 media files from site 2, Can I stop this behavior?

I want if I reference site 2 files from site 1 pages, generated link should open them from site 2 domain.

for example currently If I am browsing page 1 of site 1 and that has a link to 1.pdf of site 2, following link is generated

http://**site1**/~media/site2/pdf/1.pdf

link is working properly but site 2 files is being served by site 1 domain
I want url of the file should be as following

http://**site2**/~media/site2/pdf/1.pdf

Node:I have a custom link provider and that works very well for pages across the sites.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your custom Media Provider and register it instead of default one:

```xml
<mediaLibrary>
  <mediaProvider type="My.Assembly.Namespace.CustomMediaProvider, My.Assembly" />
</mediaLibrary>
```

```cs
public class CustomMediaProvider : MediaProvider
{
    public override string GetMediaUrl(MediaItem item, MediaUrlOptions options)
    {
        string mediaUrl = base.GetMediaUrl(item, options);
        if (mediaUrl == null || mediaUrl.StartsWith("http"))
        {
            return mediaUrl;
        }

        string[] parts = mediaUrl.Split(new[] {'/'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        if (parts.Length > 2)
        {
            // skip "~" and "media" parts
            string mediaLibraryTopFolder = parts[2];

            // assuming that folder names are site1 and site2
            SiteInfo siteInfo = SiteContextFactory.GetSiteInfo(mediaLibraryTopFolder);

            if (siteInfo != null)
            {
                SiteContext siteContext = new SiteContext(siteInfo);
                // change logic if you need https
                mediaUrl = "http://" + siteContext.HostName + "/" + mediaUrl.TrimStart('/');
            }
        }

        return mediaUrl;
    }
}
```

This code is not tested, but if the media item link does not contain host name yet, it should get the top level folder from the media path, get the site with same name as folder name and add proper host name at the beginning of the path.

Remember that this will change all your media links so they will include `http` and host name and that this will work only for links generated by the `MediaManager` or `MediaProvider`.